# SEAM integration test

Tags: java, string, exception, seam

I am writing SEAM integration test using [Oficial RedHat tutorial](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2.0.cp09/html/Seam_Reference_Guide/Seam_Reference_Guide-Testing_Seam_applications-Integration_testing_Seam_applications.html).

On running any test exception appears:

```
FAILED: testOperation
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1421)
 at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1450)
 at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.WebXml.getFacesResourceKey(WebXml.java:189)
 at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.WebXml.getFacesResourceKey(WebXml.java:222)
 at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:139)
 at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:508)
 at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
 at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
 at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
 at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
 at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
 at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$Request.run(AbstractSeamTest.java:491)
 at org.meveo.admin.action.TestOperation.testOperation(TestOperation.java:36)
... Removed 22 stack frames
```

I have found same problems in internet, but no solution:

How to solv this exception?

Answer (score 0):

set up a url pattern:

```
<web:ajax4jsf-filter url-pattern="*.faces"/>
```

From here:

http://seamframework.org/Community/RunningSeamMaven2TestNGTests